# How do I debug a lagging firefox?

Tags: firefox

I am unable to load new windows in firefox. I've had this happen two times now, once the other day and again right now, where I load URLs and I get stuck on a loading page.

It's not the internet since I can open the same url in chrome or safari just fine.

I'm not sure where to check. My extensions are the same as they were when firefox was working.

How would you investigate a problem like this?

Comment: I tried to disable my add-ons one at a time and reload a page to see if that was the problem.

Comment: A better test is disabling the add-on then restarting Firefox.  A first step of just restarting in safe mode can rule out all add-ons entirely in one step.

Answer (score 1):

What extensions are you running? Even though they are the same as they were when they were functioning, an update or change in an adblocking filter for instance could cause a website to stop loading.

I would start Firefox in safe mode (which doesn't load extensions) and see if the website loads. **Hamburger Menu** > **Help** > **Restart with Add-ons Disabled**

If it continues to not load, I would do a refresh. Just make sure you have bookmarks, etc. saved or exported first!